# Create list headings in Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I had just started with notebooks and Python. When I print my list will I just the list and then number how often they occur.

I would like to if I could get hour as a header above 12 and 8 and count as a header above 7 and 3.

```
x=df['hour'].value_counts()
print(x[0:2])
```

12  7

8   3

How I want it:

Hour .   count

12          7

8           3

For the moment am I getting this below my results *Name: hour, dtype: 
int64*

/Lisa

Comment: Or do you need `df1 = print(x[0:2]).reset_index()` ?

Comment: Can you add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Hi, I don't get what you mean by saying "above 12 and 8" or "above 7 and 3". Do you mean hour value or hour count?

Comment: I mean as a table heading. Will edit the main post

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, since the question is not so clear, but, as I understood here is my solution:

```
df[['hour', '_column_tobe_counted_']].groupby(['hour']).agg(['count']).reset_index()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe but not completely. Said that it wasn't in index.  The first line in the code looks like df = pd.read_csv('/Users/lisa/Desktop/data.log', names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python')             
          Hour    Count
              12      7
              8      3

Comment: What did you write on jupyter and then get "it wasn't in index". '_column_tobe_counted_' in my answer should be your column_name. If you provide your code snippet I can help you.